# How to draw a dash line outside drawRect method？

Tags: ios

I have a UIImageView that I want to fill a dash line,I definitely don't want subclass a UIView，then draw a dash line in it for such little piece of work, is there any way i can use to draw a dash line and then form a UIImage set to my UIImageView

Answer (score 2):

You could draw a bezier path and place it on a new layer.

For example:

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath new];

[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 20)];

[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(10, 0)];

[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(20, 0)];



CAShapeLayer *lines = [CAShapeLayer layer];

lines.path = path.CGPath;

lines.bounds = self.frame;

lines.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

lines.fillColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;

lines.lineWidth = 1;

lines.frame = self.frame;

[self.layer addSublayer:lines];
```

Comment: Is it adding line with dashes. Like ---------------